# Cannot assign function to displayExpr in dx-select-box with angular2

Tags: angular, devexpress, devextreme

A selection box for 'Sites' should show a combination of site code and description for the user to select.

Below is the html:

```
<dx-select-box class="pull-right"
                           placeholder="Select Site"
                           [dataSource]="sites"
                           [displayExpr]=displaySite
                           [valueExpr]="SiteID"
                           [value]="selectedSite"
                           [searchEnabled]="true"></dx-select-box>
```

The component code is as below:

```
displaySite = (data) => {        
    return data.Code + "(" + data.Description + ")";
}
```

The issue here is that data value in the displaySite function is always null.

The same thing works when I use lookup in  the datagrid as below:

```
{ dataField: "SiteID", lookup: { dataSource: sites, valueExpr: "SiteID", displayExpr: displaySite } }
```

Below is the version of dev-extreme I am using:

```
"devextreme": "16.2.3",
"devextreme-angular": "16.2.3-rc.3",
```

Comment: `[displayExpr]=displaySite` is this intended? Without the quotes?

Answer (score 1):

1) `[value]="selectedSite"` - If `selectedSite` has not a default value, `data` in `displaySite` function will be null. So expression, like `data.Code + "(" + data.Description + ")";` should contains a check for null and may be changed to `data ? data.Code + "(" + data.Description + ")" : null;`

2) Be careful with `[valueExpr]="SiteID"`, because if `SiteID` is a string (I suggested so from your example), square brackets in Angular means, that expression should be evaluated. Correct will be change it on `[valueExpr]="'SiteID'"` or `valueExpr="SiteID"`.

Also i'm prepared an [example on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rUxMvn1a6UpjNxvLuIZc?p=preview), that demonstrate this scenario